# Pointer-array of std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I need to have a dynamic array of strings, so that I can expand it at any time. So I wanted to do it with malloc/realloc. But every time I try to run it I get segmentation fault with following errors from valgrind:

```
==13709== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==13709==    at 0x4EEED9B: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==13709==    by 0x400953: main (test.cpp:12)
==13709== 
==13709== Invalid read of size 8
==13709==    at 0x4EEED9B: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==13709==    by 0x400953: main (test.cpp:12)
```

My code looks like that:

```
int main()
{
    string* arr;
    arr=(string*) malloc(5*sizeof(string));
    arr[0]="test1";
    arr[1]="test2";
    cout << arr[0] << arr[1] << endl;
}
```

I know about char**, but it is kind of a pain to use, so I wanted to use strings. Any hint on how to make it work?

Comment: Why don't you just make a `std::vector< std::string >`?

Comment: Just use `vector<string>` and save yourself a whole lot of grief.

Comment: What the others said. If you want to know why your code does not work, it is because `std::string` is a class and `malloc` does not call its constructor, so you basically are trying to access uninitialised objects, which causes a runtime error. As a general rule (which can be broken in some rare cases) you should not mix C style allocations (`malloc & free`) with C++ Classes (or even code if you want to be purist).

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a good idea, but I wanted to save some memory by using just plain strings without everything that comes along with vector. Oh well, thanks for the answers, will do it with Vectors then.

Comment: `malloc` is almost never used in C++, this reason being one of them. As a direct replacement, `new` works with non-POD types (like `std::string`) and a vector works even better. I'm not sure what kind of memory you're saving by not using a vector.

Comment: @chris - Does `new` have some kind of `realloc` equivalent to it, so that I won't have to create a new array and delete an old one?

Comment: @Testie Using a `vector` costs you roughly the space needed for three pointers; which is pretty much the minimum you need for a performant dynamic array. You're not paying for anything you're not using.

Comment: @AlanStokes - Well, okay, thanks for the answer, guess I'll stick with `vector` then.

Comment: @Testle No, it doesn't. You would have to allocate a new array, copy everything over, then deallocate the old array. We avoid this kind of manual memory management in C++ by letting classes manage it for us (like `std::vector`).

Comment: @Testie no, there is no such thing, but why exactly do you want to use `realloc`? Not to mention that you should never use `realloc` with `std::string` (or any other C++ class for that reason)

Comment: @UnholySheep - As I already said - `realloc` was very convenient for just adding a couple more spaces to the array, so I thought of using it in this case too.

Comment: @Testie, In general, adding a couple more spaces with a vector won't do any reallocations, so you're good. `push_back` has amortized constant complexity. There's always `reserve` if you need a bigger chunk of memory for later, too.

Comment: @chris - Well, thanks for the answer, will stick with `vector` then.

Comment: `malloc` in C++? Nope. Use `new` and `delete`, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarise the comments:

`malloc(5*sizeof(string))` will only allocate memory large enough to fit 5 `std::string`s. Class type objects (like `std::string`) need to be initialised after the memory has been allocated, which means constructing the object, before the object can be used. Attempting to use the uninitialised memory as though it were a valid initialised `std::string` object will give you undefined behaviour.

In C++, dynamic memory allocation is performed using the `new` operator. That is, your line would be written as `arr = new string[5];` instead. This allocates space for 5 `std::string`s and also constructs all of them. They are then ready to use.

However, in C++ we try to avoid performing dynamic memory allocation ourselves because it leads to bugs and unsafe code. Instead, we use classes (often those provided by the standard library) that encapsulate this behaviour. In this case, you are much better off using a `std::vector<std::string>` which represents a container of `std::string`s that can easily be added to, removed from, resized, etc. without ever having the dangers of manual dynamic allocation.

To demonstrate how much better this is, here is how I would write your code:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> arr = {"test1", "test2"};
  std::cout << arr[0] << arr[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have a dynamic array of strings, so that I can expand it at
>   any time. So I wanted to do it with malloc/realloc.
>   [...]
>   Any hint on how to make it work?

Just use **`std::vector<std::string>`**.

In this way, all the memory management happens "under the hood" *automatically*.
It will make your code *much easier* to read and to maintain.

In modern C++ (unless there is a strong reason for not doing that), consider using convenient **STL container classes**, like `std::vector`, and string classes, like `std::string`, instead of *raw* C-like pointers.

If you want to add more strings to your vector, just call `std::vector`'s **`push_back()`** method, and new room will be made for the new string, and the vector updated correctly.

And `vector`'s and `string`'s destructors will *automatically* release memory for you.

It's a big win over raw `malloc`/`free` (or `new[]`/`delete[]`).